# Изменение зависящих элементов в таблице (JS)

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть 2 таблицы:Товары и корзина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить товар" добавляется запись во вторую таблицу.
Так же, в корзине мы можем изменить "Количество", тогда должна тут же меняться "Сумма", именно этот момент и не получается реализовать

```js
function addRow(id) {
  var name = document.getElementById("gds").value;
  var count = document.getElementById("cnt").value;
  var price = document.getElementById("prc").value;
  //кусок кода где пытался реализовать изменение
  var summa = price * count;
  var add_input = document.createElement("input");
  add_input.setAttribute("type", "number");
  add_input.setAttribute("name", "numb");
  add_input.setAttribute("value", count);
  add_input.setAttribute("onchange", "changeSum(count, price)");


  var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
  var row = document.createElement("TR");
  var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
  td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
  var td2 = document.createElement("TD");
  td2.appendChild(add_input);
  var td3 = document.createElement("TD");
  td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(price));
  var td4 = document.createElement("TD");
  td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(summa));
  row.appendChild(td1);
  row.appendChild(td2);
  row.appendChild(td3);
  row.appendChild(td4);

  var td5 = document.createElement("TD");
  row.appendChild(td5);
  td5.setAttribute('onmousedown', 'this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild (this.parentNode);');
  td5.innerHTML = "Удалить";
  tbody.appendChild(row);
}
// пытался сделать функцию для изменения
function changeSum(count, price) {
  var summa;
  summa = price * count;
  return summa;
}
```

```css
#add {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

#btn {
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#basketForm {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#basketTable tr+tr:hover {
  background: #f3bd48;
  /* Цвет фона при наведении */
  color: #fff;
  /* Цвет текста при наведении */
}
```

```html
Товары
<form id="add">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Название товара: </td>
      <td>
        <select id="gds">
          <option>Молоко</option>
          <option>Хлеб</option>
          <option>Сигареты</option>
          <option>Алкоголь</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Количество товара: </td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cnt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Цена товара: </td>
      <td><input type="number" id="prc" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="addRow('basketTable')" value="Добавить в корзину" />
</form>
<br />

<form id="basketForm">
  <table id="basketTable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Товар</th>
      <th>Количество</th>
      <th>Цена</th>
      <th>Сумма</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, в функцию передадим только текущий елемент события - текстовое поле

```
add_input.setAttribute("onchange", "changeSum(this)");
add_input.setAttribute("onkeyup", "changeSum(this)");
add_input.setAttribute("onmouseup", "changeSum(this)");
```

Так же будем запускать функцию не только при изменении, но и при отпускании кнопки мыши и клавиатуры.

Далее:

```
function changeSum(el) {
    // Количество - значение переданого елемента
    var count = el.value;

    // Елемент цены - берем родительский елемент input'а (tr) и следующий от него елемент
    var priceElement = el.parentElement.nextSibling;
    var total = count*priceElement.innerText;

    // Елемент "итого" - следующий после цены
    var totalElement = priceElement.nextSibling;
    totalElement.innerText = total;
}
```

```js
function addRow(id) {
  var name = document.getElementById("gds").value;
  var count = document.getElementById("cnt").value;
  var price = document.getElementById("prc").value;

  //кусок кода где пытался реализовать изменение
  var summa = price * count;
  var add_input = document.createElement("input");
  add_input.setAttribute("type", "number");
  add_input.setAttribute("name", "numb");
  add_input.setAttribute("value", count);

  add_input.setAttribute("onchange", "changeSum(this)");
  add_input.setAttribute("onkeyup", "changeSum(this)");
  add_input.setAttribute("onmouseup", "changeSum(this)");


  var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
  var row = document.createElement("TR");
  var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
  td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
  var td2 = document.createElement("TD");
  td2.appendChild(add_input);
  var td3 = document.createElement("TD");
  td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(price));
  var td4 = document.createElement("TD");
  td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(summa));
  row.appendChild(td1);
  row.appendChild(td2);
  row.appendChild(td3);
  row.appendChild(td4);

  var td5 = document.createElement("TD");
  row.appendChild(td5);
  td5.setAttribute('onmousedown', 'this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild (this.parentNode);');
  td5.innerHTML = "Удалить";
  tbody.appendChild(row);
}
// пытался сделать функцию для изменения
function changeSum(el) {
  var count = el.value;
  var priceElement = el.parentElement.nextSibling;
  var total = count*priceElement.innerText;

  var totalElement = priceElement.nextSibling;
  totalElement.innerText = total;
}
```

```css
#add {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

#btn {
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#basketForm {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#basketTable tr+tr:hover {
  background: #f3bd48;
  /* Цвет фона при наведении */
  color: #fff;
  /* Цвет текста при наведении */
}
```

```html
Товары
<form id="add">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Название товара: </td>
      <td>
        <select id="gds">
          <option>Молоко</option>
          <option>Хлеб</option>
          <option>Сигареты</option>
          <option>Алкоголь</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Количество товара: </td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cnt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Цена товара: </td>
      <td><input type="number" id="prc" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="addRow('basketTable')" value="Добавить в корзину" />
</form>
<br />

<form id="basketForm">
  <table id="basketTable" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Товар</th>
      <th>Количество</th>
      <th>Цена</th>
      <th>Сумма</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```